# JavaScript changing values of element having the same ID dilemma

Tags: javascript, html, dom, range

So basically what I'm currently facing is kind of embarrassing, I've created a function which dynamically creates new elements and add it to the DOM. The function is replicating the elements( the same id) whenever the triggered button is being clicked. I have a range slider which when i slide should change a the p tag, the problem now is that since the p tag has been replicated with the function(all p tag has the same id) only the first p tag is being changed. I would like to know what can I do in order to solve this problem. Any help?

```js
//this function creates elements, it contains the range and //the p tag which needs to p change

function createElements(){
 
var divelement = $('<input class ="timer" type="range"  min="3" max="20" value="10"oninput="showValue(this.value)"></input><p id="changeP"></p>');
  $('#userQuestions').append(divelement);
 
}


function showValue(value){
 
 this.document.getElementById("changeP").innerHTML=value+" Minutes";
 
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="userQuestions"></div>

<button type="button" onclick="createElements()">add elements</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Run the snippet to see the problem thanks.

Comment: Having multiple elements with the same ID in the document is **invalid HTML**. You should fix that first, and then working with those elements in the DOM will be far less unnecessarily painful.

Comment: IDs should be unique. Target the class name instead using `querySelector`/`querySelectorAll` and then loop through each one using `forEach`.

Comment: Instead of an ID on your P tag use a class. Then query with something like getElementsByClassname() to get a node list

Comment: Or create a global counting variable, that increments each time createElements() is called and use that counter with your id name to make each one unique

Comment: @Ignorant23 also, input elements do NOT have closing tags... get rid of `</input>`

Comment: @Doug That method returns a (hard to work with) `HTMLCollection`. Better to use `querySelectorAll` usually, or, in this case, avoid the collection methods altogether and simply select the next adjacent element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the duplicate `id`s and simply select the next sibling, and populate its `textContent`:

```js
const userQuestions = document.querySelector('#userQuestions');
function createElements() {
  userQuestions.insertAdjacentHTML(
    'beforeend', '<input class ="timer" type="range"  min="3" max="20" value="10"oninput="showValue(this)"><p></p>'
  );
}

function showValue({ nextElementSibling, value }) {
  nextElementSibling.textContent = value;
}
```

```html
<div id="userQuestions"></div>
<button type="button" onclick="createElements()">add elements</button>
```

Comment: Wow nice! YOU SIR, ARE A GENIUS #claphands thank you.